Lines thick and blurry HTML canvas
I am drawing a simple grid, like so:
const canvas = document.getElementById('gridCanvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

// Define the size of each square
const squareSize = 20; // NxN squares

// Define the number of squares in each direction
const numRows = 10; // X
const numCols = 15; // Y

// Set the canvas dimensions
canvas.width = numCols * squareSize;
canvas.height = numRows * squareSize;

// Function to draw the grid
function drawGrid() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.lineWidth = 1; // Set the line width to 1 pixel
    context.globalAlpha = 1.0; // Ensure full opacity

    // Draw the horizontal lines
    for (let row = 0; row <= numRows; row++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, row * squareSize);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width, row * squareSize);
        context.stroke();
    }

    // Draw the vertical lines
    for (let col = 0; col <= numCols; col++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(col * squareSize, 0);
        context.lineTo(col * squareSize, canvas.height);
        context.stroke();
    }
}

// Draw the grid when the page loads
window.onload = () => {
    drawGrid() 
};

here's the HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas Grid</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }
        canvas {
            /* border: 0px solid black; */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gridCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="../dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



const canvas = document.getElementById('gridCanvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Define the size of each square
const squareSize = 20; // NxN squares

// Define the number of squares in each direction
const numRows = 10; // X
const numCols = 15; // Y

// Set the canvas dimensions
canvas.width = numCols * squareSize;
canvas.height = numRows * squareSize;

// Function to draw the grid
function drawGrid() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.lineWidth = 1; // Set the line width to 1 pixel
  context.globalAlpha = 1.0; // Ensure full opacity

  // Draw the horizontal lines
  for (let row = 0; row <= numRows; row++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, row * squareSize);
    context.lineTo(canvas.width, row * squareSize);
    context.stroke();
  }

  // Draw the vertical lines
  for (let col = 0; col <= numCols; col++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(col * squareSize, 0);
    context.lineTo(col * squareSize, canvas.height);
    context.stroke();
  }
}

// Draw the grid when the page loads
window.onload = () => {
  drawGrid()
};
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  /* border: 0px solid black; */
}
<canvas id="gridCanvas"></canvas>



But the lines it is drawing are 6 pixels thick, completely translucent, blurry, and not black. Here's a screenshot with some of it zoomed in.

When I set the line thickness to 0.5 instead of 1, the lines are still 6 pixels thick, just lighter.
My device pixel ratio is 2, but I don't understand then why the lines are 6px thick and not 2px. I ultimately want the lines to be 1 physical pixel thick on all screens.
I have tried adding the following code:
// Set the canvas dimensions in CSS pixels
canvas.style.width = `${numCols * squareSize}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${numRows * squareSize}px`;

// Set the canvas dimensions in device pixels
canvas.width = numCols * squareSize * devicePixelRatio;
canvas.height = numRows * squareSize * devicePixelRatio;

// Scale the drawing context to match the device pixel ratio
context.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);

But the lines are still 2px thick, and translucent, even when setting lineWidth to 0.5.

@mherzig this is what I see with your code (moved a bit to show you the red CSS line which is correctly 0.5px)


The lines are fuzzy because of where the canvas draws them. The center of the lines are at the pixel mark where you indicate, which means that half of the line is 0.5pt to the left, and the other half is 0.5pt to the right. That essentially gives you a double-width fuzzy line.
On the other hand, if you offset the center of the line to be half of a point, then your line's width is rendered cleanly.


const canvas = document.getElementById('gridCanvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw the grid when the page loads
window.onload = () => {
  // these two are fuzzy
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 10);
  context.lineTo(100, 10);
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(10, 0);
  context.lineTo(10, 100);
  context.stroke();

  // these two are sharp
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 19.5);
  context.lineTo(100, 19.5);
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(19.5, 0);
  context.lineTo(19.5, 100);
  context.stroke();
};
<canvas id="gridCanvas"></canvas>




No, this doesn't work. I've edited my question to show you the result of what you've posted.

@DaraJ One horiz & vert line are blurry because they are centered on the pt mark, and the other two (down and right) are sharp because they are centered on the 0.5pt mark, correct?

Also make sure you have the same width & height set in both your JS and CSS. Canvas is like an image, and has a size that you can override as you did above, but if you then set an explicit size in CSS that will not make the canvas working area larger, it will just distort what you already have.
